# Delete indexes in ElasticSearch correctly

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When I delete some data from the database *Elastic Search* "not updated" then give the restart of their service to pick up the changes. However I want to do it right and delete the data.

My code correctly deletes all indexes but when I do a search it appears terms as result with `count = 0`
 I want to delete **and don't appear in the search**, how do it?

My code

```
try {
            String formatValue = URLEncoder.encode(veiculo, "UTF-8");
            Request.Delete("http://" + PropertiesSingleton.getValue("es.host") + ":9200/oknok/base_gerenciada/_query?q=spec_veiculo:" + formatValue + "&default_operator=AND")
                    .useExpectContinue()
                    .version(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
                    .execute().returnContent().asString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error(this, "Erro ao remover do Elastic Search.", e);
        }
```

My filter in search

```
{"from": 0, "size": 0, "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"last":true}}]}}, "facets": {"filters": {"terms": {"field": "spec_veiculo.raw", "all_terms": true,"size" : 999999, "order": "term"}}}}
```

Search result

```
{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":8375,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"facets":{"filters":{"_type":"terms","missing":0,"total":8375,"other":0,"terms":[{"term":"Abril - Arquitetura & Construção","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Aventuras na História","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Bebe.com.br","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Boa Forma","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Bons Fluidos","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Capricho","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Casa Claudia","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Casa.com.br","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Claudia","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Contigo!","count":0},{"term":"Abril - Elle","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Estilo","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Exame","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Exame PME","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Gestão Escolar","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Guia Quatro Rodas","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Guia do Estudante","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Hotel Pro","count":67},{"term":"Abril - Info","count":67} (...)
```

Comment: does it throw an error when you run  the same delete query via curl ?

Comment: No, i have something like `{"_indices":{"oknok":{"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}}}`

Comment: this would mean this is an issue with the client code you are using , the client does not allow you to pass a request body with Delete request. What is the client you are using to do the request  i.e which class is Request

Comment: try using match_phrase in your delete code https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html#phrase-matching

Comment: this might [help](https://daweini.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/apache-httpclient-send-entity-body-in-a-http-delete-request/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out your delete code using [match phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html#phrase-matching).

If you already know the **`id`** of the `document` you are going to delete, try deleting using the id of document.

[Deleting a Document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/delete-doc.html#delete-doc)

Comment: I need to delete by name and not by ID will be deleted various data. The problem is the same in code, even sending empty bodyString I get the error.